# C, 2 events and timing question

Tags: c, events, timer

I will fork 3 threads,
One for event A, another for event B, third one for timing.

I will run A in every 3.2 sec, run B in every 1.7 sec.

My thought is in thread 3, at proper time, I call A or B.

Is this logic right? 
Will the calling of A and B in thread 3 influence timing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, executing one thread will influence the execution time and duration of the other threads. So will any other running processes as well as the design of your task scheduler and your thread library, not to mention the current mood of your operating system, which may decide to delay the execution of your processes/threads by an arbitrary amount of time.

If you want to make sure that your threads perform some action in certain time intervals, you have to either use an operating system which can make guarantees towards the execution of its processes, or you have to come up with a clever design which handles the case where a time interval passed without thread A or B having done (or completed) its task.